# Fitting Mancova model on factor scores

Tags: factor-analysis, manova

I have two matrices with multiple variables. The two matrices come from same sample.I would call them matrix A and Matrix B.Each of them have many correlated variables .

I would want to evaluate the relationship between matrix A and matrix B taking matrix B as explanatory and matrix A as dependent .
When i looked at the structure of Matrix A .I was able to describe it into 4 factors and matrix B into 3 factors.

I fitted a mancova model using factor scores of matrix A and factor scores of matrix B.

Is this a valid way to do the analysis.

Comment: What about factoring all the variables together - that might be informative.

Comment: Ok the reason for doing this is ,my data has four groups.The first question I am trying to answer is if matrix A variables are able to predict groups.For this i did PCA and yes my matrix A variables show clear separation between the four groups.The next question is if matrix B variables (which are biologically associated with matrix A ) are able to predict these groups and how are they related to matrix A. At first i did a combined (matrix A matrixB  Pca) and i could not see separation between the groups.Matrix B PCA alone doesnt show group separation .

Comment: Also since we know matrix B( genes) is biologically related to matrix A( variables showing metabolism) i took my matrix A (factors)as response (which is already different for different groups) and matrix B( factors ) as explanatory variable to how they are related .

Comment: I think what you propose is OK then.